# how to use flex-box for griding the page

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a container that contains two rows and one column that first-row height is smaller than the second row.
now I want the grid with flexbox as this image:

[image]

I write this:

```
.CONTAINER{
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
}

.FIRSTDIV{
    align-self: flex-start;
}

.SECONDDIV{
    align-self: center;
}
```

but the result like this:

[image]

How to achieve the first image with flex-box?

Answer (score 0):

Just add `flex-flow:column` in your container class

```
.CONTAINER{
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    border:1px solid #f00;
    flex-flow:column;
}

.FIRSTDIV{
    align-self: flex-start;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}

.SECONDDIV{
    align-self: center;
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    margin-top:20px;
}
```